# Less-Than Vs. Equal-To For Efficiency C/C++

Tags: c++, c

When I've used older APIs, for example, the C sockets API on Unix, I always notice that people favor less-than (`<`) over equal-to (`==`) when comparing their bad return values.

```
int result = send(...);
if (result < 0) { perror("..."); }
```

In the cases I'm referring to, the return code is only ever positive, `0`, or `-1` (with `errno` set to the right value).  So why not just check for an error using `(result == -1)` instead of `(result < 0)`?

I'm asking because I was wondering if it's done out of habit or if it's more efficient to use less-than?  I was thinking about the fact that if you were comparing two `uint64_t`s and you found the difference in the MSB, you wouldn't have to check the other 7 bytes, etc.  I might be reaching with this logic though!

Comment: In the specific case of checking ``< 0``, this might get hyper-optimized by the compiler.  In twos-complement, all you need to check is whether the leftmost bit is 1 to determine whether a value is less than 0.

Comment: If there _is_ an efficiency reason, it's purely historical and has entered convention via that route: such a micro-optimisation will surely never be a bottleneck (in the general case).

Comment: I think some systems calls used to return a negative value on error, not necessarily -1. Maybe this has been standardised, because I can't find any examples on my linux box. `if (result) perror(...);` would actually suffice here.

Comment: It certainly has nothing at all to do with efficency. Do you realise how fast computers are? Seriously, if there is any difference at all between the two approaches (which I doubt) the difference would be measured in micro seconds.

Comment: Tell someone in a top finance company doing arbitrage related programs that microseconds don't matter - They don't for what I do but some people tear you apart on those things in interviews, haha.

Comment: @john: it's a lot less.  w00te: actually if you tell them that a system call takes at least orders of magnite longer you might have an interesting conversation...

Comment: I think the convention is to put error code in the conditional and mainline code in the else. Which is why you see if (result < 0) vs. if (result == 0)

Comment: Is assembly, (for some processors) if there is a negative value in a register there is a flag that shows this. Don't forget those old UNIX programmers would have been aware of this and done it instinctlvely. (ps I hope you sort out your nested for loops to minimise closes.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that this is neither for habit nor for efficiency. It is safer because you don't rely on a specific return code. Instead, you rely for the error code to be negative. For instance, `strcmp` function returns "a negative value" when the first string is smaller than the second. On most implementations, it will return `-1`, but the correct way to handle it is to check for `< 0`

Comment: That's what I assume, too... it's too allow any negative code to be returned. Some functions can return multiple "error" codes, all of which are negative... e.g., "select".

Comment: @Patrick87: on which system does `select` return other negatives values? none AFAIK.

Answer (score 11):

OK, let's find out. This is GCC 4.6.1 on x86 with `-O3`, and `a` is of type `int`:

`if (a < 0)`:

```
 movl    4(%esp), %eax
 testl   %eax, %eax
 js      .L4
```

`if (a == -1)`:

```
cmpl    $-1, 4(%esp)
je      .L4
```

Here `4(%esp)` is the variable `a`, and `.L4` designates the jump destination of the conditional.

---

Update: As @yi_H suggests, now let's compare `if (h() < 0)` and `if (h() == -1)`, where `int h();` is some function. We have:

```
<       testl   %eax, %eax
<       js      .L4
---
>       cmpl    $-1, %eax
>       je      .L4
```

Comment: Can you try it so `a` is a return value of a function?

Comment: In some cases (though not in the case of a function call), for `if(a < 0)`, the compiler can skip the `testl` instruction and emit just a `js` instruction, saving you a whole cycle!  That will happen if the previous instruction which computed `a` sets the sign flag in the EFLAGS register.

Comment: @Adam: Thanks, that's interesting. The larger lesson here should be, however, that at the very best the difference is one or two CPU instructions, so performance should really be the least important of the criteria when deciding which style to favour!

Comment: @Adam - We don't even save a whole cycle, because modern CPUs try to execute 3-4 instructions per cycle, at 3 GHz. This isn't even a micro optimization, it is a nano-optimization (or less).

Answer (score 5):

This is done for robustness, not efficiency.  If you only check for specific return values, such as -1, and the API is later modified to return -1 for one type of error and -2 for a different type of error, the code will no longer behave correctly.  In most APIs a negative return value indicates error, so checking that the return value is negative to determine if an error has occurred is the robust solution.

Comment: Not really -- most functions (especially Linux system calls) which return -1 for an error usually set `errno` to the specific error code, in which case there's no chance that function will ever return -2 for a different error in the future, since they can just use more values for `errno`.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield : So rely on convention?  The terms "Not Really", "Mosy", and "Usually" are not indicative of a robust design to me.

Comment: If you modify the API you will potentially break all the existing clients. you cannot just go on and say "Let's hope that everybody checks for negative return value". that's never going to happen.

Comment: The contract of the interface is to return an int.  The calling code must be prepared to handle any returned integer value and behave appropriately.

Comment: @JadeMason: that's a vely low level contract, observed from the return type of the function. POSIX is a lot more strict than that.

Answer (score 2):

To me, the only difference in your question is about *specificity*.

checking for < 0 is a very general test, that allows some sort of "future expansion".

any kind of performance difference would be negligible on today's hardware.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a matter of less than versus equals. It's a matter of zero versus any other number. Comparison against zero (any comparison - equality, greater/equal, etc.) is generally cheaper than comparison against a specific non-zero value.

Answer (score 1):

On some architectures, comparing against zero has a shorter, and hence slightly faster, implementation.

Comment: +1, and case in point is XORing a register with itself as a zero check. But agree with Armen that robustness is the primary driver.

Answer (score 1):

Because the error code can be any number less than 0 when it is an error and you would have multiple possible error codes that would let the programmer know what is the particular error. If you only checked for one case, that would not be sufficient.